# how to not print exception by using HandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, web

```
public class AtrExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {
private final static Log log =LogFactory.getLog(AtrExceptionResolver.class);

@Override
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
    boolean ajaxrequest = false;
    if (request.getRequestURI().indexOf("/ajax/") > 0)
        ajaxrequest = true;
    if (ex instanceof AtrException) {
        AtrException atrE = (AtrException) ex;
        log.error(
                "AtrException:code:" + atrE.getCode() + ",desc:"
                        + atrE.getMsg(), ex);
        if (ajaxrequest) {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = response.getWriter();
                out.print("{\"e\":\"" + atrE.getCode()
                        + "\",\"message\":\"" + atrE.getMsg() + "\"}");
                out.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                goToError(request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } else {
        log.error("Exception:desc:" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        if (ajaxrequest) {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = response.getWriter();
                out.print("{\"e\":\"3\",\"message\":\"system error\"}");
                out.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                goToError(request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;

}

private void goToError(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/jsp/error.jsp");
}
```

`atrException` is defined by myself,so I do not want to printStackTrace() in console.only print it in log.
I debug it,found it print by standardwrappervalve.invoke().
How to not print `atrException` message in console?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then you want the exception stack trace in a String object which you can use it for logging.

You can use below method.

```
public String getErrorLog(Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable != null) {
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        return errors.toString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Returned value is stack trace which you can log.

Comment: sorry,my english is so poor.I can log the exception message.I don't want the exception print in the console.

Comment: So where do u want to print it or u want to ignore it?

Comment: like this 严重: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/prs-rec-front] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.xxx.recommend.atr.exceptions.PlanException] with root cause
com.xxx.recommend.atr.exceptions.PlanException
 at com.xxx.recommend.atr.service.PlanServiceImpl.addPlan(PlanServiceImpl.java:85)
 at com.xxx.recommend.atr.controller.PlanController.addPlan(PlanController.java:56)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: Can you debug your code and check at what line error stack is printed in console?

Comment: I solved it.I found if I return null ModelAndView,it would throw again by processHandlerException.so when I return a ModelAndView Obj,it would not print exception in console.Anyway,thank u very much.

Comment: Oh, i didn't notice it. Now you have learned to debug your code.

Answer (score -2):

```
return new ModelAndView();
```

This way can solve.